# DVB capture into ffmpeg in windows?

Tags: ffmpeg, windows, video-capture

Looking for a way to use ffmpeg dshow to open a tv capture card within windows. I have tried running the list devices command and my usb capture does not show. If it is a device limitation, Im happy to get one that does support this.

The station I want is on DVB-T.

Comment: FWIW I have a working DVBT/ATSC digital capture prototype in my local FFmpeg branch, ping me if anybody wants to be/become a beta tester :)

Comment: I'm interested in it, have you merged it? Could you give some info?